# SurfaceView and ANativeWindow

Tags: android, java-native-interface, surfaceview, nativewindow

I have a question regarding creation of a SurfaceView and subsequently getting a ANativeWindow from it.

1. Is it proper to do 
   `mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);` in:

   - `onCreate()`
   - `onStart()`

Reason for asking: as I understand it the SurfaceView will get destroyed when we lose focus (something else covers up the entire screen) so we will need to re-create it every time we gain focus (onStart() is executed). Or does the SurfaceView remain dormant and reusable?

1. Moving on, now I would like to create a native window from the above-mentioned surface (in native code). Is it proper to do 
   `ANativeWindow* newwindow = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(jniEnv, joSurface)` in:

   - `onSurfaceCreated_native(..., jobject surface)`
   - `onSurfaceChanged_native(..., jobject surface)`

Reason for asking: onSurfaceChanged seems to be always called after `onSurfaceCreated` so we have a choice as to when to create the native window. On one hand, it appears logical to do this in `onSurfaceCreated`, but the two `jobject surface` appear to be referencing different objects! (As checked by creating a weak global ref to surface in onSurfaceCreated and checking it against both NULL and surface in onSurfaceChanged, see code below)

`onSurfaceCreated_native(JNIEnv env, ... ,jobject surface) {`
`myWeakObjectGlobal = env->NewWeakGlobalRef(surface);`
`}`

`onSurfaceChanged_native(JNIEnv env, ... ,jobject surface) {`

```
if (env->IsSameObject(surface, myWeakObjectGlobal)) {
    LOGW("onSurfaceChanged_native: new surface is SAME as old surface");
} else {
    LOGW("onSurfaceChanged_native: new surface is DIFFERENT as old surface");
}

if (env->IsSameObject(NULL, myWeakObjectGlobal)) {
    LOGW("    furthermore, old surface is NULL");
} else {
    LOGW("    furthermore, old surface is NOT null");
}
```

`}`

Therefore, if there are indeed two distinct surface objects being sent into onSurfaceCreated and onSurfaceChanged, then we want to use the freshest one and not hang on to a stale surface reference, and consequently do ANativeWindow_from_Surface in onSurfaceChanged.

I would really appreciate it if someone could shine some light on this issue for me.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to share a surface between OpenGL and Java, ANativeWindow seems to be one of the only reasonable ways of doing this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `android.view.Surface` instead of `android.view.SurfaceView`?